# Broken Conda after install of Anaconda for OS X w/ Python 3.6

Tags: anaconda, conda

I installed anaconda 4.3.0 for OSX, Python 3.6.  Everything with the install seemed to go fine.  However when I try to start jupiter notebook I get:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
>       import notebook.notebookapp
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 63, in <module>
>       from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 16, in <module>
>       from nbformat import sign, validate, ValidationError
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
>       from .validator import validate, ValidationError
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/validator.py", line 12, in <module>
>       from jsonschema import ValidationError
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
>       from jsonschema.validators import (
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 8, in <module>
>       import requests
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
>       from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 47, in <module>
>       import OpenSSL.SSL
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
>       from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 13, in <module>
>       from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import dsa, rsa
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py", line 14, in <module>
>       from cryptography.hazmat.backends.interfaces import RSABackend
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
>       import pkg_resources
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in <module>
>       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
>   AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'`

When I try to run `conda` I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 617, in conda_exception_handler
>       return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 85, in _main
>       from ..base.context import context
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 17, in 
>       from .._vendor.auxlib.path import expand
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/path.py", line 8, in 
>       import pkg_resources
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in 
>       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
>   AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/bin/conda", line 6, in 
>       sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 167, in main
>       return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 633, in conda_exception_handler
>       print_unexpected_error_message(e)
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 543, in print_unexpected_error_message
>       from conda.base.context import context
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/base/context.py", line 17, in 
>       from .._vendor.auxlib.path import expand
>     File "/Users/joe/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/_vendor/auxlib/path.py", line 8, in 
>       import pkg_resources
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1423, in 
>       register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
>   AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

I did a simple remove and reinstall but the problem persists after the reinstall.  I would try to run anaconda-clean but since conda does not work, I can't install it.  Any advice?